# Is Extendscript able to duplicate a file using File Object ( File. )?

Tags: adobe, extendscript

Want to duplicate a file in a local directory with a new file extension. I don't see any documentation for duplicating a file with the File Object.

I see the ability to `File.copy()`, etc but nothing having to do with duplicating or saving without a dialog box with a new name and extension.

```js
var targetFile = new File('myFile');
targetFile.saveDlg('newFileName' + 'extension');
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. In what way does `File.copy()` not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To do it by code, you must be more explicit. You can try this:

```js
function duplicateFile(path) {
  var content, extension, file, fileOk, name, newFile, newPath;
  file = new File(path);
  if(!file) {
    return
  }

  fileOk = file.open('r');

  if(fileOk){
    //Get file extension
    name = file.name.split('.');
    extension = name.pop();
    name.join('.');

    //Creating new file
    //Becareful with the name, you must to check that a file with the same name doesn't exists
    //if you don't want to overwrite it.
    name = name + '_copy.' + extension 
    newPath = file.parent.fsName + '/' + name
    newFile = new File(newPath);
    fileOk = newFile.open('w');

    //Writing content to new file
    if (fileOk) {
      newFile.write(content);
      newFile.close(); //Remember to close the files
    }
    file.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miguel - I'll give this a try